# Rails 6 belongs_to block model update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
     
  before_create :init_setting
  before_create :init_profile

  after_create :add_gender_to_profile   // this stop working
  after_create :add_username_to_profile // this stop working
       
  private

  def init_profile
    build_profile
  end

  def init_setting
    build_setting
  end
end
```

Second model is of course `Profile`:

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I think that this should be enough of code for profile.

There are also models: Country, State, City

```rb
class Country < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :profiles
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
  has_one :country
  has_many :profiles
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :profiles
end
```

And now ... every thing works fine `add_gender_to_profile` - works, `add_username_to_profile` also works, but ...

ONLY if i throw out from Profile model association

```rb
belongs_to :state
belongs_to :city
```

If I do not throw it, I see in logs something like this:

```
Profile Exists? (3.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `profiles` 
WHERE `profiles`.`id` != 42 AND `profiles`.`slug` = 'majkel' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:66:in `add_username_to_profile'
```

Line 66 in user.rb

```rb
def add_username_to_profile
  self.profile.update(:username => self.username)
end
```

Where this created profile have `id == 42` and should have `slug == majkel`

Where is the problem? Why if I uncomment `belongs_to: state`, and `belongs_to :city` for profile model everything is OK?

OK FOUND PROBLEM, but I don't understand it yet:

```
translation missing: 
pl.activerecord.errors.models.profile.attributes.state.required
```

Comment: The error you are seeing is because some message catalogs in `i18n` don't have a complete set of translations for all standard `ActiveRecord` keys. I presume you are using a locale that has incomplete translations.

Comment: Vaguely (un)related: you have your City `belongs_to :state` already so do you need `belongs_to :state, through: :city` for your profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Rails 5, `belongs_to` requires the presence of the associated parent object or it will fail validation when you save. In your code, you are calling `build_profile` to initialize a new `Profile`, but you don't appear to create an associated `State` object at that point.

One option would be to fully configure the associated objects at creation time. Another option is to define the association as optional:

```rb
belongs_to :state, optional: true
```

Comment: thank you, now it works ... must read about that

Comment: belongs_to associations are now automatically required: true
All model's belongs_to associations are now treated as if the required: true option is present. So if the association is optional, that must be declared, or validation will fail without the presence of the associated model record.